# Login to website and then web scrape data (Python)

Tags: python, web-scraping, basic-authentication

I kindly ask you to correct me what I am wrong here. The html code I obtain is again a page with login form. What I meant to do here is to get a token during one session and then to use it to log in. What I plan to do is to use bs4 to collect some data.

```
import bs4
import requests

session = requests.session
with requests.Session() as s:
    url = 'https://www.planetplus.pl/'
    res = requests.get(url)
    data = res.text
    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(data, 'lxml')
    token = soup.find_all('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})[0]['value']
    print(token)
    payload = {'UserName': 'xxx', 'Password': 'yyy',
               '__RequestVerificationToken': token}
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)
    r = s.get('https://www.planetplus.pl/moje-konto-cashback')
    print(r.text)
```

Website link: https://www.planetplus.pl/

Well, to be honest I am a beginner, so if you could correct me and even elaborate, suggest how to do it the best, this would be great!

Additionally, how much the procedure is different for website http://www.exsite.pl/, because I delete the token part in login credentials dictionary and also the output is access restricted page html code. And do not judge websites, first found with different login type, at least different for me ;)

```
import requests

with requests.Session() as s:
    session = requests.session
    url = 'http://exsite.pl//'
    payload = {'login_name': 'xxx', 'login_password': 'yyy!'}
    p = s.post(url, data=payload)
    #print(p.text)
    r = s.get('http://www.exsite.pl/filmy_video_movies/filmy-dvdrip-brrip/1378773-ukryte-piekno-collateral-beauty-2016-plsubbed480pbrripxvidac3-krt-napisy-pl.html')
    print(r.text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working example for **https://www.planetplus.pl/**

```
import bs4
import requests


BASE_URL = 'https://www.planetplus.pl/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL + 'logowanie'


with requests.Session() as session:
    res = session.get(BASE_URL)

    soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'lxml')
    token = soup.find_all('input', attrs={'name': '__RequestVerificationToken'})[0]['value']
    payload = {'UserName': '6r5anl+fnmps358bvh8@sharklasers.com', 'Password': 'qwerty',
               '__RequestVerificationToken': token}

    session.post(LOGIN_URL , data=payload)
    res = session.get(BASE_URL)
    print(res.text)
```

Comment: Take attention on session object. If you want to use the same session then you should use the same session object.

Comment: Also take attention how I moved variables BASE_URL and LOGIN_URL. You should do the same for repeated code.

Comment: I may seem dumb, however it does now work. `BASE_URL = 'http://www.exsite.pl/'
LOGIN_URL = BASE_URL
with requests.Session() as session:
    res = session.get(BASE_URL)
    payload = {'login_name': 'xxx', 'login_password': '!xxx'}
    session.post(BASE_URL , data=payload)
    res = session.get('http://www.exsite.pl/')
    res=res.text
    print(res)`

Comment: You should write code more to improve experience. Also begin to read Mark Lutz "Learning Python".

Comment: Well, I try. However if sometimes I get stuck... And I really appreciate your help, thank you.

Comment: Could you just take a look on second web page, I applied your suggestions (in this case I see BASE_URL = LOGIN_URL and removed token) and it does not work. First webpage works like a charm. Me writing that it is not working was about second webpage...

Comment: Is it possible to do scraping past a /login while the /login is disallowed in the robots.txt?

Comment: @Mushirih, sure. robots.txt is a list of paths and commands for web crawlers which use it to understand how to index your site. To parse some site you don't need to be aware of robots.txt. http://www.robotstxt.org/robotstxt.html